# How to invoke DialogHost by a button outside of its scope?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using Material Design in my WPF MVVM project. I have the following code:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost CloseOnClickAway="True"
                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           Identifier="root"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <StackPanel Margin="20">

            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedSecondaryDarkButton}"
                    Width="160"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource ResourceKey=vazir}"
                    Margin="10,5,5,5"
                    ToolTip="Resource name: MaterialDesignRaisedSecondaryDarkButton"
                    Content="Option 1"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.ControlsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
            <Separator BorderThickness="0.5"
                       Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
            <TextBlock Text="" />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedSecondaryDarkButton}"
                    Width="180"
                    Background="Green"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource ResourceKey=vazir}"
                    Margin="10,5,5,5"
                    ToolTip="Resource name: MaterialDesignRaisedSecondaryDarkButton"
                    Content="Option 2"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.ControlsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedSecondaryDarkButton}"
                    Width="200"
                    Background="Green"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource ResourceKey=vazir}"
                    Margin="10,5,5,5"
                    ToolTip="Resource name: MaterialDesignRaisedSecondaryDarkButton"
                    Content="Option 3"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.ControlsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>

    <Button x:Name="fileDialogBtn"
            Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"
            Content="Show Dialog"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="50,0,0,0" />
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

I want to invoke this `DialogHost` by another `Button` that exists outside its scope. Using a `Button` that exists inside the scope, the `DialogHost` is invoked and shown easily, but I want to invoke it from the outside. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a boolean property in your ViewModel example :`IsDialogOpen` and bind to the DialogHost's `IsOpen` property, then make your button set this property to true using a command.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is not inside the `DialogHost` itself, but within the same [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), your can assign a name to the target `DialogHost` and specify it as [`CommandTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandtarget?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) in the `Button` that shall open it.

> Gets or sets the element on which to raise the specified command.

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="MyDialogHost" ...>
```

```
<Button x:Name="fileDialogBtn"
        Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"
        CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyDialogHost}"
        Content="Show Dialog"/>
```